# What test to use to prove no significant difference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am comparing the value obtained from a lab with the value obtained from a home meter. The value can be any number. There is no normal distribution or expected number. I am just trying to prove that the results match. I do not want a statistically significant difference between values from lab and values from home meter.

I have 20 patients - each with 1 value from the lab and 1 from the home meter.

Comment: Check [tag:tost]

Comment: Bayesian methods can quantify support for the null hypothesis (e.g., no difference between two values).

Comment: There are many a statistical tests that can detect whether there is a significant difference in estimates.based on actual data. THE tests depend on data types. PLEASE indicate your data and it's description.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot prove that they are exactly the same (without an infinite amount of data).  What you can do is show that they are equivalent.  This means first coming up with what you consider to be an equivalent region (this is determined by the subject matter expert, not the statistician/consultant/etc.).  Then there are methods to establish equivalence, the simplest is to find a confidence interval on the difference and if the entire interval falls within your equivalence region then you can declare them equivalent.

A more expanded approach is to make a [Bland-Altman plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot) to show the similarity and difference.  The references on the page linked above give a lot more detail (the first 3 by Bland and Altman are probably the most relevant to your question).